# How to iterate through result set and print to console of a JDBC request triggered from beanshell sampler

Tags: jdbc, jmeter, beanshell

Sending the following JDBC request from JMeter, using a beanshell sampler. And now I want to fetch the result as the response body fetched in JMeter showing empty but triggering the query successfully.

**Code for JDBC request:**

```
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.*;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement;

ResultSet rs = null;
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = null;
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

Connection conn = DataSourceElement.getConnection("IMPACTConnectionPrerequisitsII");
String Query = "DECLARE \n" 
           + "j number(4); \n"
           + "BEGIN \n"
           + "FOR j in 22 .. 23 LOOP \n"
           + "INSERT INTO FWA_STAGE_TU \n"
           + "(ID,EXT_ID,BATCH_NO,OPERATION,BLOCK_ROLL_UP_LAST_RECORD,LAST_UPDATED_DATE,ERROR_FLAG,TRIAL_NO,TRIAL_ALIAS_CODE, \n"
           + "COUNTRY_CODE,DISPLAY_UNIT_NO,GROUP_NO,TRIAL_UNIT_REFERENCE,PRIMARY_INVESTIGATOR,PRIMARY_CENTRE,LOCATION_NO, \n"
           + "PURPOSE_CODE,MANAGING_MED_UNIT_CODE,UPDATING_MED_UNIT_CODE,FINANCE_MED_UNIT_CODE,PATIENTS_ALL_SET_UP_FLAG, \n"
           + "PATIENT_MONITORING_FLAG,COMMENTS,CONFIRMED_FLAG,CONFIRMED_BY,CONFIRMED_DATE,ROLLUP_ROLLDOWN_PLANNED_FIGS, \n"
           + "DOC_COLLECTION_INDICATOR,VALIDATED_PAT_CAP,MAXIMUM_PAT_CAP,PREFERRED_LANGUAGE_CODE,NEW_DISPLAY_UNIT_NO, \n"
           + "TOTAL_OPEN_DCF_ISSUES_NO,ORDER_INTERVAL,ORDER_INTERVAL_UNITS,DATA_SOURCE_CODE,RANK_SEQ) \n"
           + "VALUES (j, 1, 10, 'I', NULL, SYSDATE, 'N', 102922, 'TESTTRIAL4', 'BEL', \n"
           + "j, NULL, 'BELTU'||j, 130262, 124236, NULL, 'PATTR', 'FP', 'FP', 'FP', 'N', 'Y', 'TESTTU'||j, \n"
           + "'Y', 999999, SYSDATE, NULL, 'P', 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL); \n"
           + "END LOOP; \n"
           + "END;";
try {
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(Query);
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
    }
catch(Throwable ex) {
    log.error("Error message: ", ex);
    throw ex;
}
finally {
    if (rs != null) {
        rs.close();
        log.info("!!!! ResultSet Connection Closed !!!!");
    }
    if (pstmt != null) {
        pstmt.close();
    }
    if (conn != null) {
        conn.close();
        log.info("!!!! Connection closed to database !!!!");
    }
}
```

**Connection Details in JMeter**

[image]

**Successful Trigger**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have a "ResultSet" to "iterate", looking into the [`PreparedStatement.executeUpdate()` function documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate())

> **Returns**:
>
> either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing

So at most you can get the number of rows impacted by your SQL query.

Also be informed that [starting from JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting).

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Working with a relational database](https://groovy-lang.org/databases.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)